# Why does this mechanic change the crankshaft mark, during this timing-belt change?

Tags: timing-belt, crankshaft, valve-timing, timing-set

['Renault Sandero - Fitting A Cam Belt' on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBnl2gLhgTI)

11:14 at first the mark is here.

11:30 then, later, it has changed to being further down.

a) shouldn't this mark be at 6 o'clock on the crank gear?

b) did he make an error to begin with?

In general, how is he reasoning through this?

Comment: While the guy doing the video seems to know what he's doing (in general), how he explains what he's doing leaves a LOT to be desired. If you are watching this as a "good" representation of what you would need to do to change out your own cam belt, if it is not the same as your engine, don't use it as an example of how to do the job. Almost every different engine type has a different way of doing the job. Some are a lot easier than others, especially where multi-cam engines are concerned. Find a video which shows your exact engine as an example ... I'll bet you'll find it on YouTube.

Comment: This is exactly my engine.

Comment: Then find a different source. Again, this guy seems to know what he's doing, but he doesn't know how to explain it very well.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer to this is that you can make any marks you want on the pulleys before you take the belt off.  As long as you put the belt back on with the pulleys in exactly the original position as you took the belt off, everything will be fine.

I am guessing that he manoeuvred the cam into a suitable position to mark it then added his own mark on the crank.

It is not a good idea to rotate the crank or cam with the belt off, since you need to ensure that the phase of the cam and crank are also correct, since the crank rotates twice for each rotation of the cam.

If this was a older diesel engine, you would also need to mark the position of the diesel pump pulley if it is driven by the timing belt, to ensure it went back in the same place.

Comment: Okay. Fair enough. Thanks for that response.

If you see the mark on the cam pulley to begin with, it is 180 degrees out. And he says this engine's timing is out. And then he rotates the crankshaft by one revolution to properly align the camshaft.

How is it that timing is so critical and yet the cam pulley can be out by 180 degrees?

Comment: Any ideas, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ?

How is it that timing is so critical and yet the cam pulley can be out by 180 degrees? (from See previous comment)

Comment: @jim Can you point to the times in the video when this happens, I don’t want to have to watch it all again.

Comment: Yes, skip to 09:20 (to 09:38 ish)

This is where he says, 'as you can see this engine is not timed properly'.

Comment: The engine is timed correctly, it is just that the guy is not very good at explaining what he is doing.  Since the cam rotates once for every 2 revs of the crank, you may need to rotate the crank another full revolution to get the cam markings to align.  That is what he is doing at this point.

Comment: I personally wouldn’t follow this guy for advice, since he brushes over important things.  For example after fitting the belt and tensioner, it is important to hand turn the engine in the correct direction at least 2 revolutions to check that the pulleys still align properly and that the tensioner is still correct.  If you don’t do this, you risk serious damage to the engine when you start it.

Comment: Why would you need to 'align the cam markings' if your engine is timed correctly?

Comment: It is just a way of making sure the new belt goes back on in exactly the same position that the old one came off.  Align the pulley markings, swap the belt, then make sure they still align.  Just best practice.  It is the relative positioning of the pulleys that sets the timing.

Comment: Right, HandyHowie. I see the sense there. So him saying the engine timing is out is false.

That confirms my understanding of how the engine works. But it also means you are trusting the synchronization of the pulleys, ultimately. The belt's markings are irrelevant as long as the pulleys remain in-sync.

The only reason to mark the belt is to ensure it's correctly tensioned, and is the correct length.

Comment: I think he just used the wrong words to describe that he hadn’t got the engine in the correct position for the timing marks to be aligned.  There is never a need to mark the belt, it can go on in any position. There may be a specific required direction of travel however. It is the relative angular position of the pulleys that matters.  There is a point in the video where he comments on the white line on the belt indicating that it is set correctly.  I have never seen anything like that before.  He never aligned any other marks on the belt, so why should that one line matter?

Comment: Yes. The engine itself doesn't see any hand-made markings on anything. The markings are just so that the installer knows he hasn't somehow altered the synchronization of camshaft and crankshaft.

I guess it is possible the two could be *better* aligned. For example if the belt has worn sufficiently.

So, if that is the case, then(correct me if I'm  wrong) it may be necessary to open up the valve cover to ensure the cam-pulley is in sync with the shaft. 

And perhaps the crank-pulley is properly aligned with the crank-shaft (but how, exactly? By using the 'blanking plug' (his words)?

Comment: In fact, just thinking about it... the 2 shafts(crank and cam) should be attached solidly to their respective pulleys, so perhaps if the two pulleys are not aligned, it needn't involve opening up the cam/valve cover. But it would involve rotation in the appropriate direction **without** the belt on.

Comment: That is exactly what you do, you align the pulley without the toothed belt fitted to get the timing correct.  The pulley is keyed to the camshaft so is fixed in one position. Some specialist engines have vernier adjusters on the cam pulleys to allow the pulley to be adjusted relative to the cam, so allowing adjustments smaller than one belt tooth.